# when i install my app in another mobiles,primarydark colour is changed?

Tags: android

i designed android app and installed in my android phone (ASUS ZENFONE_5),app is working fine....but when i installed "my app" in Coolpad note_3 lite mobile , app model changed like primary colourDark and DialogListView??how would i fix this issue??

this is my mobile screen shot
[image]

this is another mobile screenShot 
[image]

Comment: just remember one thing: this feature only work on api lvl 21 or above, so make sure your device is 21 or above

Comment: how do i fix this ??? i want install my app in any phone , then i will got same effects

Comment: this is not possible.. its not work on lower then api 21 device.. try to understand.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=slidenerd+style+for+primaryDark   look this tutorial for your material design understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the Highlight color and Activated color in your style.xml file

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/appcolor</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/appcolor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorControlActivated' with value '@color/appcolor').

Comment: in my style.xml file , i have taken like this .....   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: Add the  <color name="appcolor">#ffffff</color> in your color.xml file